# Allowing Remote Access on my Xampp MySQL DB

Tags: mysql, xampp

Okay I apologize in advance if this seems to be a trivial question but I am new to databases and such so here's my problem.

I have installed xampp and using their MySQL database service. I also able to connect to my database remotely in my network yet I would like to access the database that i have created from another computer out side my LAN. So far i have created a user named "Lester" with all privileges enabled and the host set to "%". In the config file i have it set as follows

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
user=mysql
port=3308
socket      =/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/mysql.sock
key_buffer=16M
max_allowed_packet=1M
table_open_cache=64
sort_buffer_size=512K
net_buffer_length=8K
read_buffer_size=256K
read_rnd_buffer_size=512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size=8M
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

How do i go about connecting outside of my network..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please specify your ip address in the bind address

```
bind-address=192.168.1.100
```

Try and let me know if you are facing any problems.

Comment: why is it specifically this ip address

Answer (score 3):

Goto

```
 http://localhost/phpmyadmin -> user accounts -> Edit privileges -> change login information
```

change Host  drop down to `Any host`

then restart mysql

reference Link

https://www.hacking-tutorial.com/tips-and-trick/how-to-make-xampp-mysql-database-accessible-by-network/#sthash.11j7Xjht.dpbs